# Poynting's theorem and escaping particles

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics, poynting-vector

I've edited my original question into horrible monstrosity (I apologize to all who spent their time on it). Here is rephrased version which hopefully will be clear.

Lets have following model situation concerning Poynting's theorem.

> *Only one standing charged particle in studied area. Energy of coulombic field is $E_1$ (yes I see the singularity too, lets leave it
>   be for the moment).*
>
> *I send in EM wave, which gets the particle move with some constant speed. Rest of the EM wave and all "junk" radiation from accelerating
>   that particle propagates away in accordance with P. theorem.*
>
> *Now I have moving point charge with constant speed. E field is a bit contracted in the direction of the movement, some B fields circles
>   around because moving charge represents current. So there is some P.
>   vector associated with fields of this moving particle. Size of this
>   overall P. vector seems to me dependent (through E, and B)  on the
>   speed of our particle.*
>
> *P. theorem will measure the flux of that P. vector when particle goes through the surface of chosen area.*
>
> *Size of that flux is through P. vector dependent on speed of the particle. And by decreasing speed I could take flux as close to zero
>   as I want.*

That's why it seems to me P. theorem doesn't register $E_1$. Have I made a mistake in my thinking?

Comment: To avoid singularity problem. Lets assume small ball of charge with finite charge density instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Poynting's theorem holds even if charges or currents are crossing the surface.

It is useful to study the proof of the theorem. It really boils down to Maxwell's equations only. Write down some multiples and/or (additional) derivatives of Maxwell's equations, add them up, and you get Poynting's theorem. Whenever Maxwell's equations hold, the theorem must hold, too.

It would be bad if charges weren't allowed to cross the surface. Indeed, charges crossing the surface are nothing else than (the elementary description of) currents and the work done by/on currents is indeed one of the important contributions to the energy conservation law that the theorem describes very well.

It's even clearer that you get a nonzero contribution to the $\vec E\times \vec B$ if you focus on the plane in between the charges.

**Two repelling charges**

Imagine they are separated in the $x$ direction. The electric fields on the $x$-axis go in the $x$-direction, too. The direction is appropriately tilted towards the $y$ or $z$-axes if we move away from the $x$-axis.

As the charges start to accelerate, one effectively gets a current in the $x$-direction and there will be magnetic fields encircling the $x$-axis. The cross product of $\vec E$ mentioned in the previous paragraph and this "around" $\vec B$ vector will include the component in the $x$-direction again, with the opposite signs on the two sides of the two-charge system (we're assuming the same signs of the charges). So this $\vec E\times B$ integrated over the transverse areas near the $x$-axis are exactly what will contribute to the equation of the Poynting's theorem.

**One point charge**

Poynting's theorem is a law in classical electrodynamics. Classical electrodynamics doesn't contain "photons". It only contains the electromagnetic waves – they are interpreted as a coherent state of many photons from the quantum theory.

It's not just a matter of interpretations. Classically, incoming electromagnetic waves are never "fully absorbed" by an object. It would violate the second law of thermodynamics, among other things. In the real, quantum world, absorption of electromagnetic waves occurs because the photons are being absorbed one by one and kick the atoms to higher discrete energy levels. But if the energy is continuous, and it always is in classical electrodynamics, there are always "soft photons" emitted and the electromagnetic field never disappears completely in the final state.

At any rate, even if you could prepare such a fine-tuned situation in which the electromagnetic wave would be entirely absorbed, the theorem would work because it always works whenever Maxwell's equations do.

Comment: Thanks Lubos, I have add my reaction into original question (since I found those comment insufficient).

Hope you won't miss it, I don't know which things cause notification here.

Comment: Dear Robitx, first of all, if I answered your actual original question, it doesn't mean that I can understand and answer any edit you add afterwards. Second, your extra edit suggests that the formulae for the energy density and density of work and the Poynting vector are random formulae that someone drunk randomly invented. It ain't so. They're essentially unique formulae that may encode the energy and its conservation, and this conservation may be proven as a mathematical theorem, just like 5+12=17. Whether some debaters in your dialogue find the formulae nice is irrelevant.

Comment: I've added one last edit which could hopefully clear out the misunderstanding of things which I wanted to ask about. And I guess I mark the question as answered and won't bother you anymore (since it looks like you labeled me as one of the people, who are stupid enough to think they can do with laws of nature whatever they please).

Comment: The question posted here now doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question you originally asked. To answer the new question, note that you won't change anything about the energy conservation if you slow the processes. If all the processes will be K times slower, then the Poynting vector will be about K times lower but so will be the rate of energy density decrease. These claims are only accurate in the much-slower-than-c "static" limit - for general electrodynamics, there are many things moving at the speed of light which cannot be slowed down, however.

Comment: Thanks, I know it looks completely unrelated (really sorry for my inability to formulate it in the first run). The decrease of energy density slows down for sure too, but with enough time all the energy which was initially inside will leave. Do I (with reduced speed) decrease the total flux that happens between $(0,\infty)$, because I am reducing size of overall P. vector? That's what bothers me a little.

Comment: Dear robitx, the Poynting vector contains the product $E\times B$. The magnetic field is created by the moving charges. If the charges move $K$ times more slowly, the magnetic fields will be decreased by the factor of $K$, too. That lowers the Poynting vector, the flux of energy, $K$ times, too, exactly by the same factor as the rate of decrease of energy. So all terms in the conservation law are lowered $K$ times. If the equation were OK before, it will be true after you slow things down, too.

Comment: When one gets to true electrodynamics where actual electromagnetic waves are escaping at the speed of light, it will be impossible to find new solutions just by slowing down the old ones. But the energy conservation law will hold at each case even if the ratios of the terms in the conservation law will change.

Comment: I am not arguing with anything you just said. My problem was elsewhere. When I look at final situation (energy moved completely from the chosen volume) I should be more careful how I integrate the flux of $E\times B$ ($K$ times smaller) over time ($K$ times longer)...

Comment: You should always be careful. But the normal formulations of energy conservation laws aren't integrated over time. They hold at each moment separately. Of course that if you integrate a function such as $\partial u / \partial t - k(t)$ that happens to be equal to zero for every $t$ over time, you still get zero. The total accumulated change of energy only depends on the initial and final configurations, so if those are kept the same, the energy difference doesn't depend on how quickly you get from the initial state to the final state.